# Prevent duplicate ActiveJob being scheduled

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activejob

I have a Rails app that queries an external webservice to update records.
I want to continue polling the web service until the user session expires.

Currently I create an ActiveJob in the show action for the record I want updated.

In the ActiveJob I reschedule it using

```
  self.class.set(wait: 60.seconds).perform_later(record_id)
```

The problem is that if the user goes to the show action again, it will create another ActiveJob.

Is there anyway to prevent duplicate jobs from being created?

Comment: Which ActiveJob backend do you use?

Answer (score 2):

The [activejob-uniqueness](https://github.com/veeqo/activejob-uniqueness) gem is designed to de-dupe jobs. The gem is still relatively new, but it's sponsored by an engineering company (Veeqo) and seems well supported. See also: https://devs.veeqo.com/job-uniqueness-for-activejob/

Comment: Yes, this is a very good gem. It creates a Redis lock for each scheduled job. Depending on uniqueness constraint, it will reject any jobs that match same signature. It can raise or notify about such events or run a custom action.

Answer (score 0):

First set a cookie value when the user visits the show for the first time.

```
self.class.set(wait: 60.seconds).perform_later(record_id) if cookies[:_aj].nil?
cookies[:_aj] = true
```

Also maybe create a column in your `Record`, maybe call it `pending_update` and set it `true` whenever you schedule a job to run and set it to `false` at the end of the scheduled job. That way, even if the user clears the cookies, your program will not create duplicate jobs.

Comment: Setting a cookie doesn't solve the problem because there are multiple users that can access the #show action.

Comment: Yes but each with  a different record to update I guess.